# Ubuntu, install doesn't find apxs

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apxs2

I try to install a packet for NTLM authentication and i get this error

> make: apxs: Command not found

I installed apache2 on ubuntu 10.10
I also installed: apache2-prefork-dev, apache2-threaded-dev, apache2-mod-php5 and apache2-mod-perl2. I also did a apt-get upgrade

But still i get the error!
If i try to locate apxs, he finds nothing. If i try to execute apxs i get an error the command do not exist if i try apxs2 as command he recognize it.

I tried to change the command in the makefile from apxs to apxs2 but that only gives me more erros

Hope someone can help!!!

Comment: I believe that apxs is for apache 1 series.
apxs2 is for apache 2 series

Comment: The strange thing is that i installed the NTLM packet with the apxs command on an other server. There i didn't have the problem. I looked for wath i installed more on the other server but didn't find much difference. If i do a locate of apxs there i find apxs and also apxs2 and the 2 commands are present.

Comment: I found a solution.
I wrongly changed the Makefile, now i changed it like this:
by putting:
aspx=apsx2
instead of
aspx=aspx